# What files to send to my iOS dev to receive a testable app back?

Tags: ios, provisioning, signing

I hired a developer. He made app.  I want to test it.

What I have:

1. Apple developer account - single - I never could figure out that
   company international ID thingy.
2. Only I can access the account (am willing to give access if that is
   only way)
3. I have OsX 10.6.2 snow lep running on Virtual Box all good
4. XCode 3.2.something (its older, updating requires new kernel and has
   been problematic)
5. (I can utilize the apple dev provisioning wizard on dev.app.com to
   obtain certs and files)
6. I have an apple certificate file downloaded to my computer that I
   made under the provisioning thingy on dev.app.com
7. iPod Touch 4g (Jailbroken) if needed. (unknown if I can access it
   via virtual box)

What I want to do...

Send whatever files to my ios developer so he can create a single file to email back to me. I take said file and install it on my iPod Touch, on my windows computer.

What do I need to send him so the developer can make this happen?  Further what do I need to tell him to do. This part may seem odd as why would "I" not knowing how to build an iOS app be telling the dev how to do it. I have requested him to make this all happen before and there is a language barrier.

What I do not want to have to do:

1. Use the mac anymore  (please tell me this is possible.)
2. (said in another way)  I would like to Test apps by putting them on my ipod Touch (using itunes or safari and dev account is ok) BUT I want to be using windows.

Can this be done?  I code Android.  I do not know Xcode and dealing with builds from Xcode 4.6 then trying to open project in Xcode 3.X not knowing if there are project errors etc. and well...learning xcode jsut doesn't make sense...I mean then why hire a dev?  yeah yeah cause he knows C++ I got that part.

Anyway, sorry for the 'flavor' parts of this message I just want to make a message that will sum up the "world of it all" for any future travelers trying to do the same thing.

Summary - I want to test apps on Ipod Touch (or whatever iOS device) using windows to install them to the device.  Able and willing to use Mac to create needed files (certs. keychain files etc.) can use Mac for all building aspects.

Please advise and thank you very much programming gawds in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Use the mac anymore (please tell me this is possible.)
>
> 2 .(said in
>   another way) I would like to Test apps by putting them on my ipod
>   Touch (using itunes or safari and dev account is ok) BUT I want to be
>   using windows.

It is possible. However, you may not understand the following steps because those should be done by iOS developer.

Step1. Your developer should archive it (In xcode, press Product, then Archive).

Step2. Open Organizer in xcode (top right corner), click the "Archives" page

Step3. Select the app you just built. Then click "Distribute" button and select "Save for enterprise or Ad-Hoc Deployment"

Step4. You will get xxx.ipa. You can drag this file in WINDOWS iTune and sync to your iPod.

Note: Your iPod should mark for "use for development" with valid provision.

Comment: This checked answer worked.  I sent the instructions to my dev and he totallyunderstood and got the job done.  Then Apple rejected the app for various static field and private API issues *slits own throat* but that is another story...so above is great :)